# Hide default version in splash screen

Tags: vb.net, winforms, splash-screen

I have a splash showing during program load on vb.net. 
I have a custom image that will show all I need, so I want to hide the default version of the program

I have following code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

' General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
' set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
' associated with an assembly.

' Review the values of the assembly attributes

<Assembly: AssemblyTitle(" ")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyDescription(" ")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyCompany(" ")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyProduct(" ")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyCopyright(" ")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyTrademark(" ")> 

<Assembly: ComVisible(False)>

'The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
<Assembly: Guid("bad8ba80-e893-4480-a4b4-5c9a91751386")> 

' Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
'
'      Major Version
'      Minor Version 
'      Build Number
'      Revision
'
' You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
' by using the '*' as shown below:
' <Assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")> 

<Assembly: AssemblyVersion("0")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyFileVersion(" 0")>
```

I have tried commenting both `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyFileVersion`, also I tried deleting them, but it still appears.

How to hide the default version of the program?

Comment: Do not edit the AssemblyInfo.vb file like this, these attributes are important.  Edit the splash screen instead.  You can alter its code anyway you want.  If you want to hide the displayed version number then just set the Label's Visible property to False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you used the SplashForm you can perform two things. You can delete the version control and any others and remove the referencing lines of code or you can set their visible properly to false.

```
Private Sub SplashScreen1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   If My.Application.Info.Title <> "" Then
        ApplicationTitle.Text = My.Application.Info.Title
    Else
        ApplicationTitle.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(My.Application.Info.AssemblyName)
    End If
    Version.Text = System.String.Format(Version.Text, My.Application.Info.Version.Major, My.Application.Info.Version.Minor)
    'Set Version controls visible property to false.
    Version.Visible = False

    Copyright.Text = My.Application.Info.Copyright
End Sub
```